# Call to a member function move() on null Laravel when file is existed

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I got error with

> Call to a member function move() on null at $request->file->move('storage/'. $filename);

```
 $application = new Application;
        if($request->file('proposal')){
            $file=$request->file('proposal');
            $filename=time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->file->move('storage/'. $filename);

            $application->file= $filename;
        }
```

Comment: you just got the file from the request with `$file = $request->file(...)` ... use `$file->move(...)` not `$request->file->move(...)` which would be looking for an input named `file` on the request

Comment: thank you for clarifying this. I was following a tutorial and wonder why I dont get the same output. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$application = new Application;
    if($request->file('proposal')){
        $file=$request->file('proposal');
        $filename=time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move('storage/'. $filename);

        $application->file= $filename;
    }
```

You are asigining request file to $file veriable and use this veriable for other operation.

Answer (score 1):

hashName()-> convert filename is random hash
i think this is best way to store files in laravel

```
$application = new Application;
if($request->proposal):
     request('proposal')->hashName();
     request('proposal')->store('your path');
endif;
```